# Looking for a optimal solution

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This was one of the interview questions in amazon. 
Given a 2D array of 0's and 1's we need to find the pattern of maximum size. 
Patters is as follows:

size = 1:

```
   1
 1 1 1 
   1
```

size = 2:

```
   1
   1 
 1 1 1 
   1 
   1
```

**Naive Solution:** Traverse each and every element of MxN matrix, and search for the index with value 1 and check if left & right entries as 1 and note the  maximum length of 1's above and below the index.

Looking for a better solution. If anyone has a clue please do post.

Comment: A more specific title and a sample of code you've tried would help.

Comment: Are there any restrictions? Can I use extra memory to hold some information?

Comment: Imagine I have a row of four ones with a column of three ones intersecting it in a way where I end up with a cross with unequal side lengths. Does that cross count as a pattern of size 1?

Comment: What is the representation of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that any 1 values that surround such a pattern do not destroy it, so that also this would have size 1:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

In that case I would suggest an algorithm where for each column you do the following:

1. Initialise *size* as 0
2. For each cell in this column:

   - Push the current *size* on a stack; it represents the number of 1 values in the upward direction starting from this cell.
   - If the value in this cell is a 1, then increase *size*, otherwise set it to 0
3. Initialise *size* as 0
4. For each cell in this column, but in reverse order:

   - Pop the last value from the stack
   - Call *thisSize* the least of the popped value and the value of *size*.
   - If *thisSize* is greater than the best pattern found so far and the values at both sides of the current cell are 1, then consider this the best pattern.
   - If the value in this cell is a 1, then increase *size*, otherwise set it to 0

As a further optimisation you could exit the second loop as soon as the distance between the current cell and the top of the grid becomes smaller than the size of the largest pattern we already found earlier.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function findPattern(a) {
    var rows = a.length,
        cols = a[0].length,
        maxSize = -1,
        stack = [],
        row, col, pos, thisSize;
        
    for (col = 1; col < cols-1; col++) {
        stack = [];
        // Downward counting to store the number of 1s in upward direction
        size = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            stack.push(size);
            size = a[row][col] == 1 ? size + 1 : 0;
        }
        // Reverse, but only as far as still useful given the size we already found
        size = 0;
        for (row = rows - 1; row > maxSize; row--) {
            thisSize = Math.min(size, stack.pop());
            if (thisSize >= maxSize && a[row][col-1] == 1 && a[row][col+1] == 1) {
                maxSize = thisSize;
                pos = [row, col];
            }
            size = a[row][col] == 1 ? size + 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    return [maxSize, pos];
}

// Sample data:
var a = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]];

var [size, pos] = findPattern(a);

console.log('Size ' + size + ' with center at row ' + (pos[0]+1) 
            + ' and column ' + (pos[1]+1) + ' (first row/col is numbered 1)');
```

Comment: This is interesting. Nice answer. I wonder, though, if it's possible to do it in a single scan per column. After all, when `size==3` in the downward scan, you know that there's a potential match at `a[row-1][col]`. I think you can eliminate the backward scan, which would also eliminate the need to maintain a stack.

Comment: When you have in the forward scan a size 3, you still need to ensure there are enough 1s in the downward direction, and as you verify this in the continuation of the forward scan, you will have greater values of size as well, which need their own proper verification. At some point you might have size 5 and then suddenly you bump into a zero. Only at that time you know that the size 5 is not good, and neither the preceding size 4. The correction of "wrong" sizes can only happen by visiting these values again, and correcting them. This is settled by the backward sweep. Curious to your solution.

Comment: My point is that when you have a length of 3 at row y, you know that there is a *potential* match of size 1 at row y-1. You could look back and check it. If you have a length of 5, you know that there's a *potential* match at row y-2. You end up doing the same amount of checking as your algorithm. You just do it all during the first scan rather than building a stack and then scanning backwards.

Comment: I posted my solution, which is the single-scan version of what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Here: [gist.github.com/...](https://gist.github.com/anandabhishek73/2088801db59e08932f9512356a48a45f) is a generic **Java** implementation that finds the largest plus(+) pattern in a 2D matrix of any size.

1. The idea is to find for the biggest possible plus(+) pattern first around the central elements(initial window) of the matrix. For each element in the window find the max plus size centered at that element.
2. If largest is found return the largest size.
3. If largest possible '+' is not found, store the size of whatever smaller than that was found and repeat search from step #1 in the next outer window around the previous window for 1-size smaller '+' pattern; iteratively searching for '+' in an 'onion layer pattern' from inside towards outside.

The initial central window is chosen such that edges of matrix are equally far on all sides from this window.

- Example 1 - For matrix of size {4x3}, smallest central window lies
  from (1,1) to (2,1)
- Example 2 - For matrix of size {3x9}, smallest
  central window lies from (1,1) to (1,7)

  ```
  int rows = arr.length;
  int cols = arr[0].length;
  int min = rows < cols ? rows : cols;
  int diff = rows > cols ? rows - cols : cols - rows;

  // Initializing initial window params. The center most smallest window possible
  int first_r, first_c, last_r, last_c;
  first_r = (min - 1) / 2;
  first_c = (min - 1) / 2;
  last_r = rows < cols ? (rows / 2) : (cols / 2) + diff;
  last_c = rows > cols ? (cols / 2) : (rows / 2) + diff;
  ```

### Full Java code:

```
public class PlusPattern {

    /**
     * Utility method to verify matrix dimensions
     *
     * @param a matrix to be verified
     * @return true if matrix size is greater than 0;
     */
    private static boolean isValid(int[][] a) {
        return a.length > 0 && a[0].length > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the size of largest plus(+) pattern of given 'symbol' integer in an integer 2D matrix .
     *
     * The idea is to find for the biggest possible plus(+) pattern first around the central elements
     * of the matrix. If largest is found return the largest size. If largest possible + is not
     * found, store the size of whatever smaller than that was found and repeat search for 1 size
     * smaller + in the next outer window around the previous window.
     *
     * @param arr    matrix to be searched
     * @param symbol whose + patter is sought
     * @return the radius of largest + found in the matrix.
     */
    static int findLargestPlusPattern(int[][] arr, int symbol) {
        if (!isValid(arr)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot perform search on empty array");
        }
        int maxPlusRadius = 0;

        int rows = arr.length;
        int cols = arr[0].length;
        int min = rows < cols ? rows : cols;
        int diff = rows > cols ? rows - cols : cols - rows;

        // Initializing initial window params. The center most smallest window possible
        // Example - For matrix of size {4x3}, smallest central window lies from [1][1] to [2][1]
        // Example - For matrix of size {3x9}, smallest central window lies from [1][1] to [1][7]
        int first_r, first_c, last_r, last_c;
        first_r = (min - 1) / 2;
        first_c = (min - 1) / 2;
        last_r = rows < cols ? (rows / 2) : (cols / 2) + diff;
        last_c = rows > cols ? (cols / 2) : (rows / 2) + diff;

        // Initializing with biggest possible search radius in the matrix
        int searchRadius = (min - 1) / 2;

        int r, c;
        int found;

        // Iteratively searching for + in an 'onion layer pattern' from inside to outside
        while (searchRadius > maxPlusRadius) {     // no need to find smaller + patterns than the one already found
            // initializing r and c cursor for this window iterations.
            r = first_r;
            c = first_c;

            // Search each of the 4 sides of the current window in a clockwise manner
            // 1# Scan the top line of window
            do { // do-while used to search inside initial window with width==1
                found = findLargestPlusAt(r, c, arr, symbol, searchRadius);
                if (found == searchRadius) {
                    return searchRadius;      // cannot find a bigger plus(+) than this in remaining matrix
                } else if (found > maxPlusRadius) {
                    maxPlusRadius = found;
                }
                c++;
            } while (c < last_c);
            if (c > last_c)
                c--; // for initial window with width==1. Otherwise #3 condition will be true for invalid c-index

            // 2# Scan the right line of window
            do {  // do-while used to search inside initial window with height==1
                found = findLargestPlusAt(r, c, arr, symbol, searchRadius);
                if (found == searchRadius) {
                    return searchRadius;
                } else if (found > maxPlusRadius) {
                    maxPlusRadius = found;
                }
                r++;
            } while (r < last_r);
            if (r > last_r)
                r--; // for initial window with height==1. Otherwise #4 condition will be true for invalid r-index

            // 3# Scan the bottom line of window
            while (c > first_c) {
                found = findLargestPlusAt(r, c, arr, symbol, searchRadius);
                if (found == searchRadius) {
                    return searchRadius;
                } else if (found > maxPlusRadius) {
                    maxPlusRadius = found;
                }
                c--;
            }

            // 4# Scan the left line of window
            while (r > first_r) {
                found = findLargestPlusAt(r, c, arr, symbol, searchRadius);
                if (found == searchRadius) {
                    return searchRadius;
                } else if (found > maxPlusRadius) {
                    maxPlusRadius = found;
                }
                r--;
            }
            // r and c comes back at first_r and first_c.

            // increasing window on all sides by 1.
            first_r--;
            first_c--;
            last_r++;
            last_c++;

            // reducing search radius to avoid out of bounds error on next window.
            searchRadius--;
        }
        return maxPlusRadius;
    }

    /**
     * Finds, if exist, the size of largest plus around a given point a[r][c]. It grows radius
     * greedily to maximise the search for + pattern returns 0 if is the point is the only symbol.
     *
     * @param r          row coordinate of search center
     * @param c          column coordinate of search center
     * @param a          matrix
     * @param symbol     search symbol
     * @param max_radius around the center to be searched for + pattern
     * @return returns -1 if the point itself is not the symbol.
     * returns n if all the next elements in E W N S directions within radius n are the symbol elements.
     */
    static int findLargestPlusAt(int r, int c, int[][] a, int symbol, int max_radius) {
        int largest = -1;

        if (a[r][c] != symbol) {   // If center coordinate itself is not the symbol
            return largest;
        } else {
            largest = 0;
        }
        for (int rad = 1; rad <= max_radius; rad++) {
            if (a[r + rad][c] == symbol && a[r][c + rad] == symbol && a[r - rad][c] == symbol && a[r][c - rad] == symbol) {
                largest = rad;   // At least a '+' of radius 'rad' is present.
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return largest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mat[][];
        mat = new int[][]{      // max + = 3
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,},
        };
        int find = findLargestPlusPattern(mat, 1);
        System.out.println("# Max + size radius is : " + find);
        mat = new int[][]{  // max + = 2
                {1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 9, 1,},
                {1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 9, 1,},
                {7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,},
                {1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 9, 1,},
                {1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 9, 1,},
        };
        find = findLargestPlusPattern(mat, 1);
        System.out.println("# Max + size radius is : " + find);

        mat = new int[][]{      // max + = 1
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 6, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        };
        find = findLargestPlusPattern(mat, 1);
        System.out.println("# Max + size radius is : " + find);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses basically the same logic as that provided by trincot in his answer, but does the reverse scan whenever there's a break in consecutive 1's. This eliminates the need to build an explicit stack.

The running time should be approximately the same. The only advantage to my method is that this algorithm uses O(1) extra space, whereas trincot's uses O(rowCount) extra space for the stack.

The extra stack makes for shorter and more readable code, though.

Code is in C#:

```
class FindPatternResult
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int Col { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
}

private FindPatternResult FindPattern(int[,] a)
{
    var numCols = a.GetUpperBound(0)+1;
    var numRows = a.GetUpperBound(1)+1;
    var maxSize = -1;
    var maxCol = -1;
    var maxRow = -1;

    // anonymous function for checking matches when there is
    // a break in consecutive 1's.
    var checkForMatch = new Action<int, int, int>((height, bottomRow, col) =>
    {
        var topRow = bottomRow - height + 1;
        for (int row = bottomRow-1; row > topRow; --row)
        {
            // There's a potential optimization opportunity here.
            // If we get beyond the midpoint and size is decreasing,
            // then if size < maxSize, we can early-out.
            // For example, if maxSize is 3 and tow-topRow < 3,
            // then there can't possibly be a longer match in this column.
            // I didn't add that optimization because it doesn't
            // really change the algorithm. But if the number of rows
            // is very large, it could be meaningful.
            if (a[row, col - 1] == 1 && a[row, col + 1] == 1)
            {
                var size = Math.Min(bottomRow-row, row-topRow);
                if (size > maxSize)
                {
                    maxSize = size;
                    maxCol = col;
                    maxRow = row;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    for (int col = 1; col < numCols - 1; ++col)
    {
        var size = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
        {
            if (a[row,col] == 1)
            {
                ++size;
            }
            else
            {
                // If size >= 3, then go back and check for a match
                if (size >= 3)
                {
                    checkForMatch(size, row, col);
                }
                size = 0;
            }
        }
        // If we end the loop with size >= 3, then check from the bottom row.
        if (size >= 3)
        {
            checkForMatch(size, numRows - 1, col);
        }
    }
```

Test with:

```
private void DoIt()
{
    var rslt = FindPattern(_sampleData);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {rslt.Size}, [{rslt.Row}, {rslt.Col}]");
}

private readonly int[,] _sampleData =
{
    {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}
};
```